# calling oneMap Rest API using php

Tags: php, rest, curl, get

I'm tying to use php to consume a restful web service from the following url.

```
http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=City Hall&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY&returnGeom=0&rset=1
```

I tried to use cURL

```
<?php
$url='http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=City Hall&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY&returnGeom=1&rset=1'; //rss link for the twitter timeline
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo($resp);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Somehow it doesn't show anything when I ran this code.

Am I missing anything? Btw this is the first time I'm trying to do such a thing.

*edit added echo($resp); but still doesnt work

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see what the problem is

Comment: i tried using `curl_error($curl);` it doesn't show anything.

Comment: `echo curl_error($curl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not consuming the API like it is meant.
When i execute the following code

```
<?php
$url='http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=City Hall&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY&returnGeom=1&rset=1'; //rss link for the twitter timeline
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
?>
```

I get

```
string(23) "Empty reply from server" 
bool(false)
```

This leads me to believe that you need to change the way you call the API. Like registering for a token.

Please follow the steps provided at http://www.onemap.sg/API/Help/  => OneMap REST APIs => Get TOken
They explain how to request a token

Comment: Thanks to you I found out whats the problem, apparently there's a mistake on my request URL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php it states that curl_exec will return true or false or the result if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set which it is. You could echo it using:

```
echo($resp);
```

---EDIT---

Having looked closer the problem is the white space and comma in the URL. Once encoded it works fine.

Here is the working URL

```
http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=City%20Hall&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL%2cCATEGORY&returnGeom=1&rset=1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I actually already tried that line but it still shows a blank page. Sorry I think I somehow forgot to add that line in my question..I'll edit it..